# How can I connect power from an end of run light switch to a 2nd light switch?

Tags: wiring

I have wired an end of run led dimmer switch with 14/3 connected to power from 14/2 before multiple LEDs, where the white of the 14/3 is just capped off. How do I connect power from the first switch to a second dimmer switch in the same box to switch more led lights? Here is how I have wired the end of run switch:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from your picture this is how you would add to it to get the second switch in a two wide box and then extending on to the additional LED lights (colored in green).

[image]

Comment: Thank-you very much Michael. Now my question is, how did you manage to mock up that diagram so darn fast ?!

Comment: Update. Just went and tried that. When I hit the breaker the 2nd set of lights came on with no control whatsoever from the dimmer switch. Couldnt even turn the lights off. All functions on the first switch work fine. Wish I could load a pic of my wiring but dont see where that is possible. Not sure if this has any bearing on it but the switches are wired for 3-way with another red wire if needed.

Comment: For the set up shown by Michael Karas, you don't use 3way switches. Your problem is the wiring is incorrect on the 3way switch. Get a single pole switch and swap it out.  If you need a 3way because of another switch also acting on the circuit, that's another wiring issue altogether.

Comment: They are Led dimmer switches which can be connected as single pole or 3-way according to the install instructions. There is a red "traveller" wire which is not used when installed as a single pole switch

Comment: Be sure not to use the traveler wire.  You have a wire wrong, go back and check all your connections.

Comment: @KenO - I doctored up the picture with Micro$oft Paint. I have a lot of practice doing things like that - although the results are not always as elegant as drawing an original in a CAD package which takes more time.